# C# - "Invalid Token" using Twitterizer

Tags: c#, twitterizer

I'm having issues with this piece of code:

```
OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens();
tokens.AccessToken = "****";
tokens.AccessTokenSecret = "****";
tokens.ConsumerKey = "****";
tokens.ConsumerSecret = "****";
```

Small program (as of request):

```
//cutted out default "using"'s
using Twitterizer;

namespace Mustache_Tweet_App
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        // config
        OAuthTokens Tokens = new OAuthTokens();
        Tokens.AccessToken = "...";
        Tokens.AccessTokenSecret = "...";
        Tokens.ConsumerKey = "...";
        Tokens.ConsumerSecret = "...";
        Tokens.RequestToken = Twitterizer.OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(Tokens.ConsumerKey, Tokens.ConsumerSecret, "");
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GetAuthKey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String AuthUri = Twitterizer.OAuthUtility.BuildAuthorizationUri();
            System.Diagnostics.Process(AuthUri);
            MessageBox.Show("Please authorize and copy the key then click OK and paste it into the the key box.", "Info");
        } 
    }
}
```

Error:

```
****.Main.tokens' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'
Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
```

Get same error on all "tokens."

Using Twitterizer 2-2-4.
also using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Where is this piece of code? In a method? Is `tokens` defined somewhere or `OAuthTokens` perhaps not?

Comment: @lc. I don't know. This is from the example code. http://www.twitterizer.net/

Comment: Can you show us how you're using this code? What you're saying and what I'm seeing don't meet.  Show us *your* small, complete program that uses this code.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Code is now added.

Answer (score 0):

The `OAuthTokens` object does not have a property `RequestToken`

Also the `OAuthTokens.ConsumerKey` and `OAuthTokens.ConsumerSecret` don't have a `get` accessor, so you can't use them the way you are doing.

Why do you wan't the request tokens? You already have them in the `Tokens` object.